# Every finite dimensional normed (real) space is isometrically isomorphic to $\mathbf R^n$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, isometry

Let $(E,\|•\|)$ be a n-dimensional real normed space.
So there exists $T:E\longrightarrow\mathbf{R}^n$ linear isomorphism that for a well known result is also a topological homeomorphism.
How could I show that there exist an isometric isomorphism $T:(E,||•||)\longrightarrow(\mathbf{R}^n,\|•\|_k)$ where $\|•\|_k$ is anyone norm?

It is simple to show that there exists a norm $\|•\|_\infty$ such that $T:(E,\|•\|_\infty)\longrightarrow({R}^n,\|•\|_\infty)$, but I want this result with the original norm, not with another one.

Comment: I don't understand the question. How can the **same** norm $\|\bullet\|_o$ be defined in **both** spaces $E$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Because the norm is the maximum absolutely value coefficent of the linear combination of a vector in the space

Comment: WHat what is $\|\bullet\|_\infty$ in an arbitrary vector space $E$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not true. If $X=\mathbb  R^{2}$ and the two norms are the usual norm and the norm $\|(x,y)\|=\max \{|x|,|y|\}$ there can be no isometric isomorphism. This is because $X$ is a Hilbert space with the usual norm so parallelogram identity holds. If there is an  isometric isomorphism then parallelogram identity would hold in the other norm also, which is not true.

Comment: I do not want to prove that there exist a isometrical isomorphism with all the norm, I want show that there exists at least one norm for which there exist an isometrical isomorphism.

Comment: Perhaps your question is answered by defining $\|x\|_k= \|T^{-1}(x)\|$ where $T$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Ah thank you it is so simple.